# Specify custom rank expression for AWS Cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I am using AWS Cloudsearch and have a field called Auth Level. It has the following values. I mean, each of the following `auth_level` is for one row.

```
"auth_level": "[ \"AUTHORISED\" ]", 
"auth_level": "[ \"AUTHORIZED\" , \"GOLD\" ]",
"auth_level": "[ \"AUTHORIZED\" , \"PLATINUM\" ]", 
"auth_level": "[ \"AUTHORIZED\" , \"SILVER\" ]"
```

I want to sort the results based on the `auth_level` value. The sorting logic should be `PLATINUM` first, followed by `GOLD,` `SILVER,` and `AUTHORISED.` I tried to add the following expression to the expressions section for using it with the `sort` option.

```
if(
  contains('PLATINUM', auth_level),
  4,
  if(
    contains('GOLD', auth_level),
    3,
    if(
      contains('SILVER', auth_level),
      2,
      1
    )
  )
)
```

So my query will be like `q=*&sort=my_rank_expression desc,` but I cannot add this as it says `invalid configuration.` How can I specify these custom sort criteria for AWS Cloud search?